# Values within a CSV file contains unquoted comma characters

Tags: java, csv

I have got a CSV file from a client where some cell contains multiple commas (,). So after splitting by comma, getting wrong value for some cells.

Example: 
for cell value of 187,859,049 I am getting 187. But I need 187,859,049.

**My code for splitting comma_**

```
        String line = "";

        //Create the file reader
        fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readfileName));

        //Read the CSV file header to skip it
        fileReader.readLine();

        //Read the file line by line starting from the second line
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //Get all tokens available in line
            String[] tokens = line.split(Constant.COMMA_DELIMITER);   
            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                //Create a new student object and fill his  data
                ShareNumber shareNumber = new ShareNumber(tokens[Constant.Cell_0],tokens[Constant.Cell_1],tokens[Constant.Cell_2]);
                shareNumberList.add(shareNumber);
            }
```

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSV fields which contain either the split character or a quote should be surrounded by quotes to indicate this, with any quotes inside the field replaced by two quotes. That's a standard rule in CSV. If the document provided by that client doesn't follow these rules, you should make them fix it, because otherwise the field is 100% unparseable.

Comment: It'd be easier to pinpoint where you could fix this if you provided the code you were using to generate this.

Comment: @Nyerguds: If OP could get his client to quote the commas, he could have gotten them to not put them in to begin with...

Comment: @einpoklum Why? They're perfectly valid data to have inside a CSV file... as long as those general rules are followed.

Comment: anything other than the client correcting their file is guesswork, and will come back to bite you

Comment: Commas inside unquoted fields are harmless... provided the *separator* is not a comma (could be a semicolon or tab for example. Have you a way to differentiate between true separators and commas inside field?

Comment: Indeed, if the separator is not a comma, or you can request the data with a specified separator, that's not a problem. My original comment specified "the split character" though; I never said "comma".

Comment: Actually,at this moment I have no way to contact with my client for data correction. But I have to submit my task asap. So need a solution if any.
@ Makoto, I have added my code.

Comment: @Sourov The only real answer to this question, in my opinion, is "get mad at whoever wrote the system that generated this corrupted csv output".

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable suggestions. BTW I have fixed this issue and added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By formatting numeric cells in following the way I have fixed the issue.**

[image: Formatting number for removing unquoted comma characters.]

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost - get your client to not put commas in the numbers they write to CSV files.

Assuming you can't do that...

You'll need to be able to tell apart "real" from "fake" commas - using information about the actual data. Specifically, you could use information on:

- Which fields are known to contain numbers
- What the value range is (e.g. is it always over 999? then a "field" that's just 3 digits long may actually be part of a larger field than a comma)
- The overall number of commas on the line; the number of "fake" commas is number-of-commas - (number-of-fields - 1). And if there's just one numeric field then this already tells you exactly which commas are "fake".

Also, this means either you don't start your processing of a line by breaking it up by commas, but rather by determining how to break it up (e.g. by matching regular expressions on it). Alternatively,you could start by breaking it up, but later on need to unify some broken-up parts of numbers.

Comment: You just summed up the specifics of the problem OP is faced with. This doesn't actually help. The _real_ problem here is obviously the client, not the parser.

Comment: @einpoklum, I have added my code. Could you review it please.

Comment: @Sourov: No. On StackOverflow, you're not supposed to add another question on the same question page after getting an answer to the initial question. If you have a problem implementing my approach, ask a new question about _that_ (and post a comment here linking to it).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your valuable suggestion. BTW I have fixed this issue and added an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I read all answers above. I think, this type of weird problem occurs due to client's file issue generally. It wastes a lot of time of developers. So developers should always try to be strict with clients for this type of issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can search for [similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour).